# How to make iOS stop asking about the same wifi

Tags: ios, wifi, alert

I spend a lot of time in a location with a secured wifi.  I don't have access to it and never will.

IOS 8 badgers me constantly to join *that* WiFi network.   Anytime I wake the iPad I have to tell it 1-2 times.  No. No. No. No. No.  How do I get iOS to stop asking about that particular network, without turning off "ask to join networks" altogether?

As you know there are several ways a notification can occur.  Badges, banners and alerts.   The "WiFi helper" always uses an Alert, which is the most intrusive one.  You know what I mean.  Is there any way to convince iOS to alert you to WiFis with a banner?  (Like my Android does?)

I know I can turn off "Ask to join networks" altogether.   I don't want to do that.  I want the feature, I just want it to behave less lamely.   Did they fix it in iOS 9 or 10?  I am reluctant to upgrade because this iPad 3 is already sluggish and freezes a lot on iOS 8.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want the Ask to Join Networks option on? Even if it's switched off you can manually go into your Settings and select Wi-Fi to see any available hotspots if you want to connect to them. I find this to be an excellent option because all the Wi-Fi hotspots I regularly connect to are remembered and I only manually need to do this if I know I'm somewhere unusual and want to search for/connect to a Wi-Fi network.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.

You can have `Ask to join networks` turned on to be notified (as you've already noticed) or off to not be notified at all. There's no intermediary position on a stock, non-jailbroken device.